# fail2ban как-то странно работает

Tags: linux, безопасность, ssh, fail2ban

fail2ban работает и блокирует айпишники которые пытаются забрутфорсить вход на сервер через ssh, но вот появился один ip, который вроде бы сидит в бане, но при этом продолжает свое грязное дельце. Я его и в ufw добавил на постоянку, закрыв доступ ко всем портам. Что можно сделать?
[image: скрин]